# command in terminal v.s. bash.sh

Tags: linux, bash, awk

i have a command and pipe into different conditions as follows,

```
cat $txt | grep -v "\/\*" | awk -F$'\t' '{if ($16=="N") print $0}' | awk -F$'\t' '{if ($48=="Y" || $48==".") print $7}'
```

this command works perfect in the terminal

However,
when I include the command in a bash.sh, it does't work at all. 
I created a test.sh 
The script just looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash     
txt=file.txt
cat $txt | grep -v "\/\*" | awk -F$'\t' '{if ($16=="N") print $0}' | awk -F$'\t' '{if ($48=="Y" || $48==".") print $7}' >> output.txt
```

Then, I simplely use

```
sh test.sh
```

It generated a output.txt, but this is no any information in output.txt

Anyone has any idea what is different ?

Comment: What happens when you put it in a script? What does the script look like? What errors or messages (if any) do you get? How do you attempt to run the script?

Comment: Did you try debugging by setting `set -x` in the beginning of your script?

Comment: The simplest way of debugging your script might be to do one thing at a time, starting with something you don't do now: Echoing the contents of `$txt`. Continue by just doing `cat $txt`. Then continue doing `cat $txt | grep ...`. And so on, verifying that each thing does what it's supposed to do. Once you find something that you don't expect, you can look closer into that.

Comment: Remove `>>output.txt` and check whether your script is generating the output or not first.

Comment: @SriharshaKalluru yes, I tried. There is no any output. I guess there is something wrong in awk. However, I have no idea how this could be different between bash and command line.

Comment: I tried both of them, your script works correctly, could you provided sample lines in file.txt

Comment: Don't invoke it using `sh`, just run the script directly.  Then the difference could be your `PATH`.  Use `echo` in the script and the shell to see what is different.

Comment: As an aside, that's a [useless use of `cat`](http://www. Iki.fi/era/unix/award.html), a useless use of `grep | awk`, and (impressively) a useless use of `awk | awk`.

Comment: Awk understands `-F '\t'`; the Bashism isn't really necessary.

Comment: Provie the contents of `file.txt` then only we can see what is missing

Answer (score 2):

Most likely sh is not bash - run as `bash test.sh` - `$'\t'` is bash and may not work in other shells - also `awk -F'\t'` works just as well

Comment: Even if  `sh` is a symlink to Bash, it will run in POSIX mode when invoked as `sh`.

Comment: Indeed, when i try bash instead of sh, it works perfect.

Comment: Indeed, when I try bash instead of sh. It works perfect. Thank you. Now, i realize that there two are not exactly the same.